Django-how to set the schema of mySql database in settings.py?
I have a database connection in settings.py to mySql database:
DATABASES = {
    
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=xxx',
        },
        'NAME': 'xxx', 
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx', #fixed
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
   }

I want to set the schema of this DB.
But settings the options like that trigger the following error:
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
TypeError: Connection.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

What is triggering the error ?

Based on the error message, there is no options setting.

        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=xxx',
        },

Above is valid for PostgreSQL but not for MySQL. MySQL requires different keys for the dictionary. 'options' is not a valid key. Below some 'working' keys:
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },

